# How to append to newly initialized Array() in single expression?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary` from which I need to have all `keys` plus one in an `Array`.

I thought:

```
let keysArray = Array(dictionary.keys).append("OneMoreKey")
```

would work. But it results in: `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value`.

What is the nicest way to do this?

Comment: By passing `dictionary.keys` through the `Array` initializer, you're making a copy of the dictionary keys into the array. Even if you fixed the immediate issue (by assigning `Array(dictionary.keys)` to a `var`, then calling `append` on it, appending to this array will have no effect on the dictionary (they're not related at all)

Comment: @Alexander I could be misintrepeting the question but I don't think he cares about changing the keys inside the actual dictionaries. Since that wouldn't make any sense because a dictionary needs a value to go with the key. Rather, I think he's literally saying he wants all the keys from the dictionary into an array plus 1 more item.

Comment: @meaning-matters Oh I see. The title threw me off. "How to add one key to Dictionary.keys?" made me think that by this line of code, you intended to mutate `dicationary.keys`.

Comment: @meaning-matters I would edit the question and give it a new title. Really, it has nothing to do with `dictionary.key`, it could be `string.characters`, and the question would still be the same: "How to append to newly initialized array in a single expression?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append to the array of keys by doing:

```
let keysArray = Array(dictionary.keys) + ["OneMoreKey"]
```

The problem with `append` is that it is attempting to mutate the non-variable array of keys.

Comment: Congratulations with 200k under name. The flip from 199 to 200 happened seconds ago. Apparently SO rounds 199,501 up :-)

Comment: Yep, once you reach 100k, it's rounded to the nearest 1000. This answer put me there (200k).

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would adding the extra element look inside `Array()`? So: `Array(dictionary.keys ???)`